# How to make culture setting match the OS setting in Blazor WebAssembly?

Tags: html, localization, blazor, blazor-webassembly, currentculture

Chrome, Firefox, and Edge all seem to use the OS's setting, not the client's "Accept-Language" setting, in determining what **date format** to use in the  control.  My problem is, the rest of my site uses the "Accept-Language" setting to determine the date format.  So, if the user's settings disagree in the browser vs. OS, as seems to be common, I might a date string shown on the page with a MM/dd/yyyy format in one place and a dd-MM-yyyy in an input element on the same page

Now I don't mind going either way with this as long as it is consistent. **How can I make it so browser's date input and Blazor's .ToString() use the same date format** even when the browser and OS have different settings?  I see here directions on how to [use the Accept-Language header automatically (sent based on client's browser settings)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=webassembly#dynamically-set-the-culture-from-the-accept-language-header-1), but it seems that HTML input controls don't respect this and instead use the OS setting.

Can I change the input[type=date] control to use the Accept-Language setting for its format, rather than the OS setting?

Assuming I cannot, can it be done the other way around? How do I make the rest of my Blazor WebAssembly site use the culture of the OS as the current culture rather than as specified in "Accept-Language"?

Here's a screenshot of my site with the contradictory date formats.  My OS (Windows 10) is set to "English India", and my Accept-Language in the browser is "en-US".

[image]

For the above example : here is my Windows setting and the browser client setting.

[image: Windows setting]
[image: Browser Accept-language setting]

Comment: Your claim around `type="date"` is in direct contradiction with [this demo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=webassembly#demonstration-component-1).

Comment: O, but that docs page seems to be wrong about using Invariant culture for type=. That makes it match my (custom) OS settings too. Aside from that your issue appears to be "as designed" .  How would omitting `type=` work in your situation?

Comment: Yes, that page also notes "When using the date and number field types, specifying a culture with @bind:culture isn't recommended because Blazor provides built-in support to render values in the current culture."

Comment: So "as designed" there is no way to have the same date format in inputs vs. strings unless OS and browser setttings match?  In other words my site will be inconsistent and I have to tell users to fix their browser settings?  They won't like that, hmm, I wonder what I can do...

Comment: You mean avoiding the date picker altogether?  Then it wouldn't be a date at all.  I think I'd have to move to a Blazor date picker component that doesn't use the formatting of the input[type=date] HTML element, which would be a shame because the built-in HTML date picker is everything I need otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a way to do this with the native browser `<input type="text"/>`, as it appears to use OS control that uses the OS setting.  I believe this to be a missing feature in most browsers.

The only fix I found was to switch to a third-party Blazor component such as RadzenDatePicker for all my date inputs.